# KendoUI web custom theme

Tags: kendo-ui

I am using **KendoUI** web widgets in my enterprise app. I need to create/customize a **Theme** as our corporate branding. After reading the docs, I realized that there is a tool called **ThemeBuilder** for this purpose available here http://demos.kendoui.com/themebuilder/web.html

Now I need to understand the logic behind the color options this tool (ThemeBuilder) shows me. All the Themes are based on 4 primary colors as shown in the selection options. However, when i try to modify/customize any theme, I found that there are more to it? How the ThemeBuilder is calculating all other colors besides the 4 Theme colors?
If I need to create my own corporate theme with 4 primary colors, how do I pick rest of the colors as shown in ThemeBuilder?

On the second note, ThemeBuilder can generate css and less. Is there a way to generate Scss as we are using scss in our organization?

Does Telerik provide scss version of their source styles. I know they provide css and less in their source directory. But converting them to scss looks like a nightmare to me!

Appreciate your help.

Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to manually convert less into scss.
I have variablized their stuff make it compatible with org's themes and colors.